# How do I pass these API arguments with the OpenAI Transcription (Whisper) feature? The documentation is poor

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I want to pass the temperature parameter to the OpenAI audio transcription API. It's easy via a direct call, as described in the API documentation:

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/createTranscription?lang=node

But I've been using the Node.js `openai` lib for other features and want to keep using it for consistency. Here's the source code for the implementation: https://github.com/openai/openai-node/blob/master/src/resources/audio/transcriptions.ts

But I've tried:

```
openAiApi.createTranscription(
    fs.createReadStream(filename),
    "whisper-1",
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    0.5 // temperature
)
```

And this throws the error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
      at createError (node_modules\openai\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
```

But if I only pass the first two arguments, it works.

Full example:

```
const openai = require("openai");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });
console.log('process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY', process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY)
const configuration = new openai.Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openAiApi = new openai.OpenAIApi(configuration);
const fs = require('fs');
openAiApi.createTranscription(
    fs.createReadStream(filename), // .mp3 file works
    "whisper-1",
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    0.5 // temperature
)
```

It seems to be from the source that this should work. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me what your `openai` package version is? Please tag me when you answer so that I'll get a notification.